# sonar qube is throwing vulnerablity issue for xss in authentication entrypoint

Tags: java, authentication, sonarqube, http-status-code-401

I am trying to override the standard error response in case of 401 in springboot using authenticationentrypoint

in commence method
I am building my custom error object which involves below line

```
 String responseMsg = mapper.writeValueAsString(responseObject);
 response.getWriter().write(responseMsg);
```

the above solution works absolutely fine but sonarqube throws vulnerability issue

is there any alternate to this or how can i overcome the sonarqube [error](https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-5131)

thanks in advance

**Update:-** I resolved it by using the solution in the link and then replacing the unwanted chars

Comment: The link you provided already explains three possible solutions and has sample code for one of them. What problem are you having implementing it?

Comment: It is telling you to encode.  In the example, it is taking an input variable (String), and encoding it before passing it to the write() method..  `org.owasp.encoder.Encode.forHtml(name);`

Comment: if i am using the method descibed i am getting distorted output when i am expecting a json response

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions below: per SonarQube  https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-5131/
for errors like

> This use of java/io/PrintWriter.write(Ljava/lang/String;)V could be
> vulnerable to XSS

**Encode for HTML**

```
import org.owasp.encoder.Encode;

public void endpoint(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException
{
    String data        = request.getParameter("input");
    PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();

    writer.print(Encode.forHtml(data));
}
```

**Set Content Type**

```
public void endpoint(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException
{
    String data        = request.getParameter("input");
    PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();

    response.setContentType("text/plain");
    writer.print(data);
}
```